# Configuring MySQL for InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm converting a lot of tables from MyISAM to InnoDB (you've convinced me) and I'm wondering what recommendations as to my MySQL configuration you guys might have...

I'm running a 16GB of RAM with 4x QUAD Core 3.0 GHz processor.

```
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 1024M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1500
table_cache            = 128
thread_concurrency     = 4
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 2M
query_cache_size        = 32M
query_cache_type        = 1
#
# * Custom Configuration
#    
tmp_table_size          = 512M
max_heap_table_size     = 128M
join_buffer_size        = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/